# Thermal equilibrium in general relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, thermodynamics

The Newtonian condition for thermal equilibrium for a static system is $T = \mathrm{const}$.

In this homework I'm asked to show that it's curved space generalization is $T(-g_{00})^{\frac{1}{2}} = \mathrm{const}$, where $g_{\mu \nu}$ is the metric (assumed stationary). But I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 2):

The clearest and most general derivation of this result is given in MTW's Gravitatiom p. 567-568 using the laws of thermodynamics in GR.

A simplified argument is in the "Problem book in relativity and gravitation" by Lightman et al. as (solved) exercise 14.2

The physical argument goes like this: imangine a black body *higher up* in a static gravitational field connected with a optical fiber to a *lower* black body. It emits a certain number of (thermal) fotons in a certain time with a certain frequency. They descend to the *lower* black body and arrive with a higher frequency (gravitational blueshift) with a different arrival time. The *lower* black body also emits a certain number of fotons with this higher frequency and if you calculate these quantities with GR and [Planck's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) you can see that a higher temperature is necessary in the *lower* black body (to equate the number of incoming/outgoing fotons) where the ratio of the temperatures is the same as that of the frequencies (look at the exponent in the denominator of Plank's law).

anyway, in my opinion this homework seems to me rather difficult if you have not been  given the appropriate background during the course (thermodynamics in GR).

Answer (score 0):

Well T is an average energy and in general relativity, there is no guarantee of energy conservation if the metric isn't stationary, so I guess that may be the problem? You could have a system at equilibrium but the evolution of the metric could change the energy.

Comment: Hmm, I'm assuming a stationary metric, sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: I think the problem might be that the energy just happens to look different in different regions of space due to the time dilatation that the $g_{00}$ bring (the energy density is a variation wrt this, after all). A particle might come from a region where $g_{00}$ has a certain value, move to a region where that value differs, and as a result totally change energy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That makes sense, but I still can't turn it into some kind of rigorous argument

Comment: @chase.furlong: what is the generator of time translations?  How does this relate to the energy?  What woudl be a sensible generalization of the statement that "energy density is constant" to curved spacetime?

Comment: Conservation of energy density in curved space time could be translated into saying that the covariant divergence of the stress energy tensor is null. Don't know how the temperature figures in that though

Comment: I didn't quite get the first part of your reply, sorry. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You don't want conservation of energy here, conservation of energy holds even outside of equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! Still haven't understood much more though. Could you be a little more concrete?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where to start either but one could think of the black body radiation coming from a source far away that was emitted by a source at temperature $T_1$ where $g_{00}$ had some value say $g_{00}^1$.

Now,if we make use of the fact that $g_{00}$ influences the photon frequency via gravitational Doppler effect, then imagining balance of energy fluxes with another body at temperature $T_2$ and $g_{00}^2$ probably leads to the relation you have to find.

Sorry it's a bit hand waving for now...